# CORS error on Axios PUT request from React to Spring API

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest, axios, put

I am working on an update functionality using PUT. I have a React front end and Spring back-end API. Here is the following PUT request made from front-end:

```
updateStuff(username, id, stuff){
    return Axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/stuff/${username}`, {stuff})
}
```

Controller to handle this request:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:3000")
public class StuffController {

        @Autowired
        private StuffService stuffService;

    @PutMapping(path="/stuff/{username}/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Stuff> updateStuff(@PathVariable String username,
                   @PathVariable long id, 
                   @RequestBody Stuff stuff) {
    Stuff response =  stuffService.save(stuff);
    return new ResponseEntity<Stuff>(stuff, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I am able to use the same service for GET and DELETE. I am also able to send request using REST client. But when I am trying using browser I am getting this error in console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/stuff/abc' from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
 Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access- 
 Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

PUT http://localhost:8080/stuff/abc net::ERR_FAILED
```

Not able to figure out why its just happening for PUT request? How to resolve this? Appreciate your help and time!

EDIT:
Updated the front-end to:

```
    updateStuff(username, id, stuff){
    return Axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/stuff/${username}`,             {
            headers:{
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            }
        })
    }
```

Still its throwing the same error. So far Spring Security is not configured. I am just checking a simple update flow without any authentication or authorization.

EDIT 2: Request headers in browser has Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *:
[image]

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe

Comment: Thanks @Khabir the post you shared is helpful to understand why the issue is happening but even after allowing CORS on back-end in addition to adding headers on front-end(which I just edited in question) its throwing the same error.

Comment: Hi @SiddharthShankar , how did you solve this problem? I have done all the cors configuration in the Spring backend. But react fetch is still giving me the error. In Postman, it is working fine.

Comment: Hi @SiddharthShankar, got same error, did u solve it ?

Comment: The issues arisis mainly due to CrossOrigin but you have mentioned in Springboot app [@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:3000")]. You can also check the port number where your react app is working. I think @nicolabaechi has stated the correct answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue a while ago. Check if the variables of your model class in the backend have the same name as in your frontend. That fixed it for me.

Comment: This is actually a pretty good answer even if it does not solve the original issue. Spring is pretty strict with the request parameters and it will give you a CORS on the actual request if your parameters do not match what the server expects. Pretty annoyting issue to debug because your preflight passes and the actual request fails with CORS making you look the wrong places for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this cors policy is to add a proxy field in the pakage.json file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpsvr.png)

Answer (score 0):

In reactjs application you can use your spring boot api's URL as proxy to avoid CORS issue.
package.

1. package.json

> {
> "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/",
> "dependencies": {
> .
> .
> .
> }
> }

2. axios

> Axios.put(`stuff/${username}`, {stuff})